Problem with loki ERROR: Unable to detect local IP address, try passing --host argument
Problem witn running npx loki --requireReference --reactUri file:./storybook-static with the error: ERROR: Unable to detect local IP address, try passing --host argument. When adding the host argument, the error doesn't go away: npx loki --requireReference --reactUri file:./storybook-static --host 127.0.0.1 --port 6006.
I also had this issue with npx loki test, but when I add the host argument, the command works: npx loki test --host 127.0.0.1 --port 6006.
Node: 18.0.0
Storybook: 8.2.2
Loki: 0.35.0
If I go into node_modules and modify the file create-chrome-app-target.js, replacing the line const ip = getLocalIPAddress(); with my IP const ip = '127.0.0.1';, the command works.
I tried changing versions, but the error persists with both "target": "chrome.app" and "target": "chrome.docker".
any guesses ?
running npx loki --requireReference --reactUri file:./storybook-static --host 127.0.0.1 --port 6006 works correctly

can you change the tag. LokiJS is a different thing altogether
